# EXCEL DSUM FUNCTION Calculates criteria that has both the same first word

Tags: excel, vba

I've created a simple inventory/sales list for peripherals. It is a very long list and I have multiple criteria that have the same first-word **Example: Mouse and Mouse Pad**. My problem is that when I used the **DSUM** function in order to get the total sales for the **Mouse** Criteria, The DSUM also Included the total sales for the **Mouse Pad**. I already know that it was due to both having the same first-word **"Mouse"** . I tried several workarounds for this such as changing capitalization or even removing space but it does not work. What worked though is that I just changed the name for the mouse pad into a desk pad in order to avoid this issue. But  I would like to ask what would be the most efficient solution for this, like what can I customize to my DSUM function so that it will include all the value in the cell for validation.

Check this images for better understanding of the issue.

**Unfiltered List with wrong calculation:**

[image]

**Filtered list for Mouse and Mouse Pad with wrong calculation:**

[image]

**Correct Calculation for total sales of Mouse**

[image]

**unfiltered List for Mouse and Renamed Desk Pad with right calculations:**
[image]

Comment: Try to enter `="=Mouse"`

Comment: Okay, Thanks. It works properly now.